# Laravel: Display of validation errors not shown

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I'm having a problem viewing validation errors in the blade view; this is the code below.

**Controller (ClientController)**

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'surname' => 'required',
        'diagnosis' => 'required',
    ]);

    Client::create([
        'name'=>$request->name,
        'surname'=>$request->surname,
        'city'=>$request->city,
        'diagnosis'=>$request->diagnosis,
    ]);
    return redirect(route('client.index'))->with('message','The customer was successfully saved');
}
```

**View (client.create)**

```
<x-layout>
    <div class="container">
        @if ($errors->any())
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        @endif
        <form action="{{route('client.store')}}" method="post">
            @csrf
            <div class="row mt-3">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="name" class="form-label">Nome</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control p-3" name="name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="surname" class="form-label">Cognome</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control p-3" name="surname" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="diagnosis" class="form-label">Diagnosi</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control p-3" name="diagnosis" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-5 py-3 px-5 mt-3 ms-3">Add</button>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</x-layout>
```

I have followed the documentation but am unable to understand where the problem is.

[Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors)

Thanks to those who will help me

**CONTROLLER UPDATE:**

```
 /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('client.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'surname' => 'required',
            'diagnosis' => 'required',
        ]);
        
        //dd($request->all());

        Client::create([
            'name'=>$request->name,
            'surname'=>$request->surname,
            'city'=>$request->city,
            'diagnosis'=>$request->diagnosis,
            'stay'=>$request->stay
        ]);
        return redirect(route('client.index'))->with('message','The customer was successfully saved');
    }
```

Index is a blade view that contains the customer table (this works fine).
The problem is the error messages I would like to see in the create view if an input is required and not compiled

Comment: What is the result you are getting, and what is the result you are expecting?

Comment: @RobBiermann for example, if I don't put the name, since it is obligatory, I should expect the error (since the name field is required). Instead nothing is displayed

Comment: Ok, to be clear, by 'nothing', you mean a white screen?

Comment: @RobBiermann yes, I stay on the form without displaying (above the form) the error as I requested in the view

Comment: did u try to put it in a variable and then dd it?
$validated = $request->validate...
and then dd it after create to see what you get back...

Comment: Can you check the file: `Http/Kernel.php` and see if `$middlewareGroups` contains `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,` in the `web` array? If so, can you tell me in which file you registered your `client.store` route? Can you show the full definition of this route?

Comment: @RobBiermann yes it is present. This is my path: Route::post('/storeclient', [ClientController::class, 'store'])->name('client.store'); present in web.php

Comment: @cile1993 yes, nothing is happening

Comment: Maybe you stored the cache? Have you tried to run `php artisan cache:clear` ,`php artisan route:clear` or `php artisan view:clear`?

Comment: @RobBiermann yes nothing happens. Yet the code looks correct

Comment: Maybe ctrl+f5 to clear browser cache of the page?

Comment: @RobBiermann also done this but nothing

Comment: dunno see issue here. probably error is somewhere else for what we don't see any code...
U could try with request validation on separate: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: this is what I did on validation. Nothing else. Need to add more code?

Comment: @Sarah Can you show the controller and function running the view you presented?

Comment: @RobBiermann What do you mean? I've already put it on

Comment: @Sarah You show the `store` function. I mean the function in the controller that does `return view('client.index');` and shows the blade view you shared.(im assuming its called like that but i dont know ofc)

Comment: @RobBiermann done, see above please

Comment: @Sarah Thanks for letting me know. So you have a route(i guess `client.create`), that calls the `ClientController@create` , that calls the view `client.create`. This all seems fine. Can we verify the `create` function is triggered by putting `dd();` before the `return view('client.create');`?

Comment: @RobBiermann Yes exactly. It works correctly because the data is also saved on the database. Thanks to you anyway. I'm going crazy about this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248582/discussion-between-rob-biermann-and-sarah).

Comment: @Sarah updated my answer to explain why required on input and laravel validation are good to have together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after checking all components, it has been under our nose the whole time.
All your inputs have the `required` attribute:

```
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="name" class="form-label">Nome</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control p-3" name="name" required>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="surname" class="form-label">Cognome</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control p-3" name="surname" required>
</div>
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="diagnosis" class="form-label">Diagnosi</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control p-3" name="diagnosis" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

This way the request is not sent, because the browser actively needs to fulfil all requirements to start the request to `client.create`

If you would remove one of these attributes and then not fill it in and submit, it will cause the errors to show.

However, we concluded that it is better to keep the `required` attribute in, as it is better to prevent a call to the webserver than to only let laravel do the work of validation.

The laravel validation is more useful for ajax/api calls, where there is no frontend to prevent you from making the request, like this:

```
//required jquery
$.ajax({
    url: '/your/url/here',
    method: 'POST',
    data: [
        name: 'somename',
        surname: 'somesurname',
    ],
    success(response) {
       console.log('Yay, it succeeded')
    },
    error(error) {
    //I havent worked with jquery in a while, the error should be in error object
      console.log(error);
    }
})
```

Or how I like to do it in vue, with axios:

```
//requires axios
axios
.post('/url/here', {
    surname: 'somesurname',
    diagnosis: 'somediagnosis',
})
.then(response => {
    console.log('Yay, it succeeded')
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log('Error', error)
})
```

You can see in the last two examples, as there is no frontend to prevent this request from being made, you now at least make sure laravel is not going to run it's logic with missing variables, which would cause a crash.

Comment: perfect, thank you infinitely